# Good way to get phase difference between vectors?

Tags: matlab

So I have two vectors:

```
>> [phase exp_phase]

ans =

    0.2266         0
   -0.0702         0
   -0.0070         0
   -0.0854         0
    0.0888         0
    3.1403   -3.1416
   -2.9571   -3.1416
   -0.1441         0
   -0.2660         0
    2.8749   -3.1416
    0.0126         0
   -2.9309   -3.1416
    0.0064         0
```

phase is obtained by atan2(b,a). I want to figure out the phase difference. The problem is that I obviously want the difference between -3.00 and +3.00 to be  roughly 0.28, but at the same time I want the difference between -2.72 and +3.00 to be the same.

It's probably trivial but I can't figure  out a good way to do it :(

Comment: Phase difference between what and what? What are b and a? What is exp_phase?

Answer (score 0):

say you have two angles, w1=+3 and w2=-3 (both in radians).
to find the smallest angular difference, do the following:

```
atan2(sin(w1-w2),cos(w1-w2))

ans =

   -0.2832
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding the phase with arctan, then I assume you have two vectors already in Cartesian coordinates, and you used atan2 to get the phase value of the polar coordinates. Just find the phase difference in Cartesian coordinates directly.  I might be messing up this formula (my trig is rusty so google it), but it is something like acos((a . b)/|a||b|).  If this is the correct formula, it gives the phase difference for two vectors, anyway there is "a" formula for this calculation in Cartesian coordinates.   You might be able to avoid the atan2 function twice (unless you also need to know the actual phases).